# ingresar elementos en una lista, que no sean iguales a los existentes. C#

Tags: c#, visual, studio

Como contexto: El programa es un ejemplo de listas a través de una pizzería, cuando se agrega una pizza se pregunta por la cantidad de ingredientes (sólo puede ser de 2 ingredientes o más). al momento de la captura SÓLAMENTE se puede capturar el mismo ingrediente una sola vez, es decir, un mismo ingrediente no se puede repetir para la misma pizza. ¿Cómo puedo lograr esto? Adjunto código.

Tengo distintas clases para el programa, van en este orden:
Clase Program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pizzeria
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Menu menu = new Menu();

            menu.MenuPizza();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        
      


    }
}
```

Después clase Menú, aqui hago la mayoría de las acciones, básicamente declaro los objetos para llamar las clases. Intuyo que podría ser directamente en la opción 1 del menú, cuando estoy insertando los ingredientes, buscar en la lista de ingredientes existentes y ver si hay el mismo que se está intentando insertar para de esa forma pedir que inserte otro.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pizzeria
{
    class Menu
    {

        public void MenuPizza()
        {

            Cocina cocinaObj = new Cocina();
            Pizza pizzaObj = new Pizza();
            Ingredientes ingredientesObj = new Ingredientes();
            int costopizzatotal = 0;
            int costopizzabase = 100;
            int costoTotalPizzaDia = 0;
            int opc = 0;
            string nombrePizzaAux = null;


            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Elige una opcion\n" +
                "\n1.- Agregar una nueva Pizza." +
                "\n2.- Mostrar listado de Pizzas preparadas." +
                "\n3.- Mostrar ingredientes de alguna pizza preparada." +
                "\n4.- Mostrar el costo de todas las pizzas preparadas en el día hasta este momento.");



                opc = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (opc)
                {
                    case 1:

                        //Añadir pizza
                        pizzaObj = CapturarPizza();
                        cocinaObj.AgregarPizza(pizzaObj);

                        //Crear ingrediente y agregarlo a la pizza
                        do
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("¿Cuántos ingredientes desea?");
                                pizzaObj.cantIngredientes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            }
                            catch (Exception errorCaptura)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(errorCaptura.Message);
                            }
                        } while (pizzaObj.cantIngredientes <= 1);

                        for (int i = 0; i < pizzaObj.cantIngredientes; i++)
                        {
                            ingredientesObj = CapturarIngrediente();
                            cocinaObj.AgregarIngredienteAPizza(pizzaObj.Nombre_Pizza, ingredientesObj);
                        }

                        List<Ingredientes> IngredienteDePizzaCosto = new List<Ingredientes>();
                        IngredienteDePizzaCosto = cocinaObj.ListadoDeIngredientesEnPIzza(pizzaObj.Nombre_Pizza);
                        foreach (Ingredientes ingrediente in IngredienteDePizzaCosto)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Nombre del ingrediente: {0} -\tCosto: {1} -\tCantidad en gramos: {2}",
                                ingrediente.Nombre_Ingrediente, ingrediente.Costo, ingrediente.Cantidad);

                            costopizzatotal += ingrediente.Costo;

                        }
                        costopizzatotal += costopizzabase;

                        costoTotalPizzaDia = costoPizzasDia(costoTotalPizzaDia, costopizzatotal);

                        Console.WriteLine("El costo total de la pizza es: " + costopizzatotal);


                        costopizzatotal = 0;


                        ingredientesObj = null;
                        pizzaObj = null;
                        break;


                    case 2:

                        //Listado de pizzas
                        List<Pizza> lstPizzaAux = new List<Pizza>();
                        lstPizzaAux = cocinaObj.ListarPizzas();
                        foreach (Pizza c in lstPizzaAux)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Nombre: {0} - \t Tamaño: {1}",
                          c.Nombre_Pizza,
                          c.Tamaño);
                        }

                        break;

                    case 3:

                        //Listado de Ingredientes de una pizza
                        List<Ingredientes> IngredienteDePizza = new List<Ingredientes>();

                        Console.WriteLine("Escriba el nombre de la pizza de la cuál desea saber sus ingredientes:");
                        nombrePizzaAux = Console.ReadLine();
                        IngredienteDePizza = cocinaObj.ListadoDeIngredientesEnPIzza(nombrePizzaAux);
                        foreach (Ingredientes ingrediente in IngredienteDePizza)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Nombre del ingrediente: {0} -\tCosto: {1} -\tCantidad en gramos: {2}",
                                ingrediente.Nombre_Ingrediente, ingrediente.Costo, ingrediente.Cantidad);

                        }

                        
                        break;

                    case 4:

                        Console.WriteLine("El costo del total de pizzas es: " + costoTotalPizzaDia);

                        break;

                }
            } while (opc != 5);

        }

        //Capturas
        public static Ingredientes CapturarIngrediente()
        {
            Ingredientes ingredientes = new Ingredientes();

            Console.WriteLine("Nombre del ingrediente: ");
            ingredientes.Nombre_Ingrediente = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Cantidad: ");
            ingredientes.Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Costo: ");
            ingredientes.Costo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            return ingredientes;

        }
        public static Pizza CapturarPizza()
        {
            Pizza pizza = new Pizza();

            Console.WriteLine("Nombre de la pizza: ");
            pizza.Nombre_Pizza = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Tamaño: ");
            pizza.Tamaño = Console.ReadLine();


            return pizza;

        }

        public int costoPizzasDia(int costdia, int costpizza)
        {
            int costototal = costdia + costpizza;

            return costototal;
        }

    }
}
```

Después, a través de la clase del menú pasa a la clase cocina, donde genero la lista de pizzas y agrego pizzas a lstPizza y de la misma forma los ingredientes que corresponden a cierta pizza que previamente se inserta en la opcion 1 del menú:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pizzeria
{
    class Cocina
    {
        private List<Pizza> lstPizza;

        public Cocina()
        {
            this.lstPizza = new List<Pizza>();
        }

        public void AgregarPizza(Pizza pizza)
        {
            lstPizza.Add(pizza);
        }


        public void AgregarIngredienteAPizza(string nombre_Pizza, Ingredientes ingredientes)
        {

            foreach (Pizza p in this.lstPizza)
            {
                if (p.Nombre_Pizza == nombre_Pizza)
                {
                    p.AgregarIngrediente(ingredientes);

                }
            }
        }



        //Listados
        public List<Pizza> ListarPizzas()
        {
            List<Pizza> pizzas = new List<Pizza>();

            foreach (Pizza p in this.lstPizza)
            {
                pizzas.Add(new Pizza
                {
                    Nombre_Pizza = p.Nombre_Pizza,
                    Tamaño = p.Tamaño
                }

              );

            }

            return pizzas;
        }

        public List<Ingredientes> ListadoDeIngredientesEnPIzza(String nombre_Pizza)
        {


            List<Ingredientes> IngredientesXPizza = new List<Ingredientes>();
         

            foreach (Pizza p in this.lstPizza)
            {
                if (p.Nombre_Pizza == nombre_Pizza)
                {
                    IngredientesXPizza = p.ListadoDeIngredientes();
                }
            }
            return IngredientesXPizza;
        }

    }
}
```

Después, de la misma forma que asigno la pizza, incluyo los ingredientes en mi clase Pizza a través de lstingredientes, es aquí donde pongo la restricción a través del atributo cant_ingredientes para que sean 2 o más.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pizzeria
{
    class Pizza
    {

        private string nombre_Pizza;
        private string tamaño;
        private int cant_ingredientes;

        public int cantIngredientes
        {
            get { return cant_ingredientes; }
            set
            {
                cant_ingredientes = value;
                if (cant_ingredientes <= 1)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Debe capturar al menos 2 ingredientes.");
                }
            }
        }
        private List<Ingredientes> lstIngredientes;

        public string Nombre_Pizza { get => nombre_Pizza; set => nombre_Pizza = value; }

        public string Tamaño { get => tamaño; set => tamaño = value; }


        public Pizza()
        {
            this.lstIngredientes = new List<Ingredientes>();

        }

        public void AgregarIngrediente(Ingredientes ingredientes)
        {
            this.lstIngredientes.Add(ingredientes);

        }

        public List<Ingredientes> ListadoDeIngredientes()
        {
            List<Ingredientes> lstAuxIngredientes = new List<Ingredientes>();
            lstAuxIngredientes = this.lstIngredientes;

            return lstAuxIngredientes;

        }
    }
}
```

Por último la clase ingredientes donde solo coloco atributos.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pizzeria
{
    class Ingredientes
    {
        private string nombre_Ingrediente;
        private int cantidad;
        private int costo;

        public string Nombre_Ingrediente { get => nombre_Ingrediente; set => nombre_Ingrediente = value; }

        public int Cantidad { get => cantidad; set => cantidad = value; }

        public int Costo { get => costo; set => costo = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
public void AgregarIngrediente(ingrediente)
{
    var contIngredientes = (from i in listaIngredientes 
    where i.NombreIngrediente == ingrediente.NombreIngrediente
    select i).Count(); 

    if (contIngrediente == 0)
    {
        listaIngredientes.Add(ingrediente);
    }
```

Lo que se hace aqui es una consulta Linq, que va a contar todos los elementos de la lista que son iguales al nuevo ingrediente que quieres añadir, si ese conteo da cero quiere decir que ese elemento no existe en la lista, por tanto puedes añadirlo, si ese conteo da un numero mayor a cero quiere decir que ese elemento ya existe por lo que no se va a añadir ya que estaria duplicado.

Para usar Linq debes poner en los usings:

```
using System.Linq;
```